# File searching in Operating Systems

Tags: file, search, operating-system

How does any operating system searches a file in its directories, when a user submits a file name? I have been given a task to make a file searching software for Window.

Does OS use Parent child relation to store files in directories and folders. Or use some other way!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand filesystem concepts like inodes and directories(essentially inodes!), to be in a position to understand how this works. As far as implementation goes, well its upto you really! As a useful exercise, you may want to download the linux source code from kernel.org. And check out the ext2 documentation in that. Really well written basic explanations on all this!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to looking into  [DirectoryInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8s2fzb02%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)